# WiFi and data usage are not reflected properly when the date is changed manually

Tags: wi-fi, mobile-network

I set the date to November 26th of next year and then used the data through the hotspot function. However, if you check the data usage, the data usage from November 26, 2024 to December 25, 2024 is 0. I am curious about the criteria for counting data usage and if there is a way to resolve this.

Comment: Could you explain what you are trying to do?

Comment: Also, where did you set the date?  Perhaps a screenshot of that screen.